# Authorization in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm new in Angular2. I would much appreciate if there is somebody who can help me to sort my problem out.
I would like to implement an authorization mechanism per route (as it is at this [link](http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/), but with the new RouterOutlet).

I've tried to extend the RouterOutlet and I've received the following error: 'Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent''

Comment: Have a look at [the official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for the latest router mecanism. Also look at [this part](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) for details about authorizations.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this feature. Is there possible to make difference between unauthorized and access denied (login required) by role?

Comment: That's a good question. I think you will need to do it yourself within a AuthGuard. And you could have a function inside canActivate() that check the access type of the current user. I mean, that's how I would try to do it with jwt.

Comment: Yup. I've started to do the same. It seems to be the last solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the blog post you mentioned is too complicated and uses deprecated API. An simpler solution is to protect the route without the need to create additional router outlet.  Use router guards to allow to navigate to the route if the user was authenticated. I blogged about using router guards here: https://yakovfain.com/2016/07/20/angular-2-guarding-routes/

Comment: Thanks. It could help me but not entirely. I would like to make difference between unauthorized and access denied (login required) . Maybe implementing a resolver before route loading.